# Difference ToString() or string assignment ? Which is faster?

Tags: c#

One way:

```
string s1 = "1";
string s2 = s1;
```

Other Way:

```
int s1 = 1;
string s2 = s1.ToString();
```

Which is faster and why?

Comment: You're really asking if there is a difference between calling a method that converts an integer into a string and just assigning a variable to point to an existing string?

Comment: These statements aren't even the same. What are you trying to compare? And why?

Comment: _"Which is faster and why?"_ https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: In your first example you don't do any conversion, `ToString` does

Answer (score 0):

`s1.ToString()` is, compared to numerical calculations, *hideously* expensive. And it will happen at runtime.

`String s1 = "1"; String S2 = S1;` will be faster due to string internment.